# Scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d do not get deployed for the Mongodb Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I'm using the mongodb chart and trying to run init scripts to seed the database. I cloned the mongodb chart into my project folder and added a files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder in it.

So the import.sh script is in the /charts/mongodb/files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder.

I deploy the chart without problems. I then get a shell to the container and check the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder only to find out it's empty.

Is there something else that needs to be done to make this work? I may be following a wrong path, since I couldn't find a single example on how to use this with mongodb and tried the information shared under postgresql and mariadb.

Answer (score 1):

The Bitnami MongoDB® image supports the use of custom scripts to initialize a fresh instance. In order to execute the scripts, two options are available:

- Specify them using the *initdbScripts* parameter as dict.
- Define an external Kubernetes ConfigMap with all the initialization scripts by setting the *initdbScriptsConfigMap* parameter. Note that this will override the previous option.

The allowed script extensions are `.sh` and `.js`.

In the *values.yaml* you can find an example:

```yaml
## @param initdbScripts Dictionary of initdb scripts
## Specify dictionary of scripts to be run at first boot
## Example:
## initdbScripts:
##   my_init_script.sh: |
##      #!/bin/bash
##      echo "Do something."
##
initdbScripts: {}
## @param initdbScriptsConfigMap Existing ConfigMap with custom initdb scripts
##
initdbScriptsConfigMap:
```

+info:

- https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/2a7003154f50945ef4f5bafcb331473881ca88b3/bitnami/mongodb/values.yaml#L267
- https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb#customize-a-new-mongodb-instance